# Lambda batch item failures not working with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to use the option to return just the failed messages back to the SQS for re-processing with the [Reporting batch item failures feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#:%7E:text=%22USER_INITIATED%22%0A%7D-,Reporting%20batch%20item%20failures,-When%20your%20Lambda).

The Lambda terraform code:

```
module "lambda" {
  source  = "xxxx"
  version = "0.0.0"

  lambda_function_name    = "${local.basename}-lambda"
  lambda_function_handler = "lambda.handler"
  lambda_payload_path     = var.lambda_payload_path
  role                    = aws_iam_role.xxxxxxxx.arn
  timeout                 = var.lambda_timeout
  memory_size             = var.lambda_memory
}

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "trigger" {
  event_source_arn = aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn
  function_name    = module.lambda.lambda_arn
  function_response_types = ["ReportBatchItemFailures"]
}
```

The SQS terraform code:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "queue" {
  name              = "${lower(local.basename)}"
  kms_master_key_id = var.kms_sqs
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 300
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "allow-s3-notification-policy" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.queue.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn}",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": { "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

This is my Lambda handler Typescript code that returns the response back to the SQS:

```
const batchItemFailures = [];
const batchItemFailures: SQSBatchItemFailure[] = [];
if(failedMessageIds.length === 0){
   return {"batchItemFailures": batchItemFailures};
} else if(records.length === failedMessageIds.length){
    console.error(`Failed to handle messages: ${failedMessageIds}: ${JSON.stringify(records)}`);
    batchItemFailures.push({ itemIdentifier: null });
    return {"batchItemFailures": batchItemFailures};
} 

const failedMessages = records.filter(record => failedMessageIds.includes(record.messageId));
failedMessageIds.forEach(id => batchItemFailures.push({ itemIdentifier: id }));
console.error(`Failed to handle messages: ${failedMessageIds}: ${JSON.stringify(failedMessages)}`);
return {"batchItemFailures": batchItemFailures};
```

On the other hand, when I'm throwing a regular error to the queue, it re-process all the batch over again.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be really helpful to see the logs of one run that didn't work, or even just a single log from that final `console.error` output.

Comment: @MarkB The console.error output is not related to the actual output of the Lambda because I”m changing the structure of the response to match it to the batch failure feature.

Comment: Well how about adding some more logging them? How about logging `batchItemFailures` before you return it?

Comment: @MarkB I did it and it printed to following result: 
`{"batchItemFailures":[{"itemIdentifier":null}]}`

Comment: OK, so you've got `null` instead of your expected list of IDs. Thus you need to do some debugging to figure out what is going on with your code.

Comment: @MarkB By the AWS documentation, if l”m returning null it supposes to re-process the entire batch from the beginning.. but it is not doing that, its not reprocessing anything

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I think by `null` Item ID what they are really referring to is a completely null item in the list that they cannot process correctly. If you want the whole thing reprocessed why not just return all the IDs, or throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your event source mapping (as stated in the link you've provided):

> include the value ReportBatchItemFailures in the FunctionResponseTypes

This value should be passed as an item of array of strings ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_EventSourceMappingConfiguration.html#:%7E:text=Type%3A-,Array%20of%20strings,-Array%20Members%3A%20Minimum)) and it looks like this if using YAML SAM/Cloudformation templates (see the last two lines):

```
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: path/
      Handler: index.handler
      Events:
        MySQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt MyQueue.Arn
            BatchSize: 20
            FunctionResponseTypes:
              - ReportBatchItemFailures
```

Let me not to write the Terraform version since I have no quick options to test the correctness of that. But I guess you've got the idea: your Lambda is not fully configured for reporting batch item failures yet.
There is a quick option for you to check if this is the root of your problem, just toggle it on in AWS Console replacing temporarily the Lambda trigger:
[image]